# Windows 11: how to unhide recycle bin icon when all desktop icons are set on hidden?

Tags: windows, icons, desktop

I set my desktop icons hidden, but I need only the recycle bin. How to unhide it without changing the settings of the other desktop icons?

Comment: Pin the Recycle Bin to the Start Menu.  That should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You may select the desktop icons you wish to be shown by:

- Run *Settings > Personalization > Themes*
- Click on *Desktop icon settings*
- Select you desktop icons
- Click OK.

You may also run directly this dialog by executing the following command:

```
"C:\Windows\system32\rundll32.exe" shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL desk.cpl,,0
```

Comment: I have a desktop crowded with folders and icons. So I set up the same to hide the icons; if I need to I use windows explorer to search for what I need but if I need to restore a deleted file I need to have the recycle bin handy. I tried as you said but no desktop with just the recycle bin visible.

Comment: I understood you wanted to return the Recycle Bin icon to the desktop. Did you rather want to combine the actions of minimizing all windows and displaying the Recycle Bin without showing the Recycle Bin icon itself on the desk? This also can be done.

Comment: I'd like to display along with the recycle bin, all the file and/or folder icons  I need.

Comment: Display how, if they're not on the desktop? There are alternatives such as creating a folder on the desktop that is closed unless opened, a folder on the taskbar, etc. Or perhaps you could use something like [Stardock Fences](https://www.stardock.com/products/fences/) (€11.99/year) to better organize your desktop